# Three js, spotlight / shadow camera cut off

Tags: javascript, three.js

Im facing a problem im trying to resolve for a few hours..
Any help would be welcome

[image: a busy cat]

I got a spot light in the scene ( imported from a collada file ), i cant understand why my shadow is cutted of.

If i show up the camerashadow helper, the helper stop exactly where the shadow cut off.
I tried a lot to move it, but nothing append.

There is the setting i apply to my spot light.

```
if (child instanceof THREE.SpotLight) {


        if(child.name == 'R_LIGHT_Spot-01'){

            console.log(child)

            child.castShadow = true;

            child.shadowBias = 0.02;

            child.shadowCameraNear = 0.1;
            child.shadowCameraFov = 35;
            child.intensity = 2.2;


            child.shadowMapWidth = 2048; // default is 1024
            child.shadowMapHeight = 2048; // default is 1024
            child.shadowDarkness = 0.1; // default is 512

        }



    }
```

And there is the renderer option for shadows :

```
renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to set the property `shadowCameraFar` on your child object.

Comment: It seems like Collada kills every light parameters ( you cant set back light parameters after the light was loaded ), i just rebuilt the light myself and it works thank you